# Showing that if $a$ is a transitive set then $\cup a$ is also a transitive set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am working on a problem in Enderton's text on set-theory that appears to be deceptively easy. It is likely that I making a mistake somewhere so if someone can comment it would be much appreciated.

Question: Show that if $a$ is a transitive set then $\cup a$ is also a transitive set.

Answer so far: Assume that $a$ is a transitive set. By definition, $\cup a = \{x \in y \ |$ for some $y \in a$}. Since $a$ is transitive, whenever we have for every $x \in y \in a$, we have $x \in a$. But these are just the conditions of set $\cup a$. So $\cup a$ is transitive.

Comment: There might be better duplicates, but that's the first one I found.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x \in y \in \bigcup a$. By your argument above, $y \in \bigcup a$ implies that $y \in a$. Then $x \in \bigcup a$ by definition of $\bigcup a= \{x : (\exists y \in a)(x \in y)\}$.

Comment: You forgot a dollar sign to end your math.

Comment: @user46944 I guess I was not holding the shift button and wrote just 4.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've made an adjustment to my argument as follows:

We show that  if $a$ is a transitive set, then $\cup a$ is also a transitive set. Assume that $a$ is a transitive set and let $X \in Y \in \cup a$. We show that $X \in \cup a$. By definition, $\cup a = \{x \in y \ |$ for some $y \in a$\}. So $Y \in a$ and $X \in a$ since $a$ is transitive. But then $X \in \cup a$ by the definition of $\cup a$. So $\cup a$ is transitive.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $w\in\cup a$,  then  there is $a_i\in a$, such that $w\in a_i$,  how $a$ is transitive then $w\in a$, and if $x\in w$ then by definition of union $x\in \cup a$.

How $x\in w\in\cup a$ implies $x\in \cup a$, then  $\cup a$ is transitive.